# The best and quickest method for detecting quadratic shape in image using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, feature-detection

In last few days I'm looking for good and quick method for finding quadratic shape in image.

For example, take a look at attached image.

I want to find the edges of white screen part (the TV screen in this case).

I can replace the white canvas with whatever I want, e.g. QR code, some texture, etc. - just looking for the coordinates of that shape.

Other features of the shape:

- Only one shape should be detected.
- Perspective transform should be used.

[image: Source: Google.com]

The languages is not that important, but I want to use OpenCV for this.

Comment: I've updated the answer for perspective transform but for detecting just one shape you should have criteria eg pattern, colour, size

Answer (score 1):

These are good algorithms that have been implemented in OpenCV:

Harris corner detector as `GoodFeatureToTrackDetector`

```
GoodFeaturesToTrackDetector harris_detector (1000, 0.01, 10, 3, true);
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
cvtColor (image, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY);
harris_detector.detect (gray_image, keypoints);
```

Fast corner detector as `FeatureDetector::create("FAST")` and `FASTX`

```
Ptr<FeatureDetector> feature_detector = FeatureDetector::create("FAST");
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
cvtColor (image, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY);
feature_detector->detect (gray_image, keypoints);
```

Or

```
FASTX (gray_image, keypoints, 50, true, FastFeatureDetector::TYPE_9_16);
```

SIFT (Scale Invariant Feature Transform) as `FeatureDetector::create("SIFT")`

```
Ptr<FeatureDetector> feature_detector = FeatureDetector::create("SIFT");
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
cvtColor (image, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY);
feature_detector->detect (gray_image, keypoints);
```

**Update** for perspective transform (you must know 4 points before haned):

```
Point2f source [4], destination [4];
// Assign values to source and destination points.
perspective_matrix = getPerspectiveTransform( source, destination );
warpPerspective( image, result, perspective_matrix, result.size() );
```